# How to get the second electron affinity of tellurium?

Tags: software, reference-request, electron-affinity

I need the value of the second electron affinity of Te, i.e. the energy change associated with the attachment of an electron to a $\ce{Te-}$ anion
$$\ce{Te- + e- -> Te^{2-}}$$
In the books (e.g. J. Huheey, E. Keiter, R. Keiter; Inorganic Chemistry: Principles of Structure and Reactivity, 4th Ed.) I find second electron affinities only for certain elements from the periods 2,3,4 of the Periodic Table but not for tellurium.

I found a paper<sup>[1]</sup> that shows how to calculate the second electron affinities, for different elements, and gives an example how to do it for the oxygen.

The calculations use Coulomb and exchange integrals $\mathrm{J_{xy}}$ and $\mathrm{K_{xy}}$ for two electrons in different 2p orbitals, and with the same spin.

Do I understand correctly, for tellurium, I need the values of these integrals for two electrons in different 5p orbitals, and with the same spin?

Is there any software package where I can calculate these integrals or is there a paper or a book where these values are calculated? Is there another way to calculate the second electron affinity of Te or a paper where it is calculated or measured?

**Reference:**

1. Pearson, R. G. Negative electron affinities of nonmetallic elements. *Inorg. Chem.* **1991,** *30* (14), 2856–2858 [DOI: 10.1021/ic00014a008](https://doi.org/10.1021/ic00014a008).

Comment: Calculations of negative ions are less reliable than those of positive or neutral particles, and those of _doubly_ negative ions are worse still. Second electron affinity is a _tricky_  thing. I guess many elements don't have it at all.

Comment: You can certainly always calculate a second electron affinity in as given methodology, if you can measure this, and whether this is reliable is a completely different story.